# open() call successful even with no permissions

Tags: c, unix

I have a file called test with no rwx permissions (I have removed all the permission using chmod)

[root@dev]# ls -l test
----------. 1 root root 21 Sep  7 22:22 test

Q1) I am trying to run the below code to check if the file can be opened or not. The value returned to fd is positive. Shouldn't fd be -1. ?

```
    fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        /* Print error message */
        return (-1);
    }
    close(fd);
```

Q2) I am even able to cat the file. Shouldn't there be an error when I cat the file.
[root@dev]# cat test
This is a test file.
[root@dev]#

NOTE: I am using root account.

Comment: Now you know why it is important not to use `root` privileges any more than minimally necessary; the system does not stop `root` from doing things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: root can do anything.

Longer answer: In general, to open a file in a given mode, POSIX requires that the permissions based on your uid and gid allow you the requested type of access, *or that you have "appropriate privileges"*, a phrase which is implementation-defined. In most real-world implementations, one such condition that satisfies "appropriate privileges" is being the root user (uid 0).